# how i can write test virus?

Tags: website, anti-virus, virus, upload

i have a website and in website some people can upload files .... and when user upload file it must scan from virus by antivirus ... so i need test virus have the following extention (.doc ,jpg, png, jpeg, gif, doc, docx, pdf, xls, xlsx ) to sure the antivirus work correctly

Comment: Crossposting is frowned upon. http://serverfault.com/questions/190526/how-i-can-write-test-virus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already been done, take a look at the [eicar test file](http://www.eicar.org/anti_virus_test_file.htm). You can try renaming the extension then uploading it.

Comment: i try it but when i test it it give me the mime file invalied ???

Comment: That's a good sign. Your upload script can detect when people simply change file extensions by looking at the MIME type.